# How to make a Python list of all the z-values of vertices on a plane, then manipulate them over time?

Tags: python, scripting

I made a Python program the other day that simulates an [Abelian Sandpile Model](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model), and I'd like to visually represent and animate this information. However, I know little-to-nothing of Blender's Python module(s).

What I would like to do is, first, write a function that generates a square plane with a vertex at every whole unit. In my finished code, I have a function called `make_area(x_length, y_length)` that works as follows:

```
area_object = make_area(5, 5)

# output below
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I would like those zeros to correspond to the z-values of each point in the plane.

The next step would be to programmatically change one of those zeros to a power of 2. My code has a function for this as well:

```
make_sandpile(area_object, (3, 3), 2**12)

# output below
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 4096, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Then, over time, each vertex would be checked for height and "toppled" accordingly.

(see: [Numberphile - Sandpiles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MtEUErz7Gg) for the logic behind this)

I already have the Python code all written and tested, but I have no idea how to translate this into Blender's Python module(s) and make a 3D animation of it. Any help you could provide would be massively appreciated!

As context, my code is listed as "An interactive variant to the above solution:" on the [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Abelian_sandpile_model) page, under the Python header.